# Page<T> empty content

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I'm try using PagingAndSortingRepository in Spring Boot for RESTFul.

```
 @Repository
public interface PrsMainRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<PrsMain, String> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM PagingFilter(?1,?2) ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<PrsMain> findAll(String colName, String condition, Pageable pageable);
}
```

This is my main repository, when i run project and test with postman i get hibernate logging:

```
2017-12-25 15:20:32.370 DEBUG 7532 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : SELECT * FROM PagingFilter(?,?) ORDER BY ? limit ? offset ?
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM PagingFilter(?,?) ORDER BY ? limit ? offset ?
2017-12-25 15:20:32.434 TRACE 7532 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [prs_firstname]
2017-12-25 15:20:32.441 TRACE 7532 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [Sharon]
2017-12-25 15:20:32.456 TRACE 7532 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARBINARY] - [Page request [number: 6, size 10, sort: UNSORTED]]
2017-12-25 15:20:32.738 DEBUG 7532 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : SELECT * FROM PagingFilter(?,?)
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM PagingFilter(?,?)
2017-12-25 15:20:32.747 TRACE 7532 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [prs_firstname]
2017-12-25 15:20:32.755 TRACE 7532 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [Sharon]
```

This is return empty content of data. I don't know why, how to resole this ?
(only SELECT * FROM PagingFilter(?1,?2) is working)

```
{
"content": [],
"pageable": {
    "sort": {
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true
    },
    "offset": 60,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "pageNumber": 6,
    "paged": true,
    "unpaged": false
},
"last": true,
"totalElements": 12,
"totalPages": 2,
"size": 10,
"number": 6,
"sort": {
    "sorted": false,
    "unsorted": true
},
"numberOfElements": 0,
"first": false
```

}

Comment: it smells like pagination number start with **1**. can you check?

Comment: tks @krezus , sorry i don't focus it. pagination number 6 greater than totalPages

Comment: check your instance where you get from pagable interface. and check page index. pls check this [example](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-data-part-5-paging-and-sorting) and [this](http://www.thejavageek.com/2017/02/26/pagination-spring-data-jpa/)

Answer (score 0):

it smells like a common mistake about giving page index. see the documentation about **[PageRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html)** .

> Pages are zero indexed, thus providing 0 for page will return the first page.